# Green's function for Helmholtz equation for the plane with a hole

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, greens-function

That is find $G$ which satisfies

\begin{align}
(\nabla^2+k^2)G(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y},\omega) = \delta(\mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y})
\end{align}

subject to $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial y_n} = 0 ~~~~~\mathrm{on} ~~~~~~S$$ where $S$ is the unit circle centered on the origin. The domain should be taken to mean the exterior of $S$. This means the normal derivative is zero on the boundary. I use the notation with $\omega$ because it is implied that the forcing is at frequency $\omega$. This follows from the wave equation. Note that I would ideally like the 2D version of the above, that is $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,x_2)$.

Comment: I have the following confusions: 1. Does the equation define on the interior of S? If that is the case, why you said '...for the plane with A HOLE'? 2. the gradient operator is defined respect to both $x$ and $y$? And what the mean about $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y_n}=0$? Is that means the partial derivative to $y$ is equal to 0?

Comment: Sorry! I meant on the exterior of S. The boundary condition just means that the  $ \nabla G \cdot \mathbf{n} = 0$. Here $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit normal pointing into the the exterior of S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Green's Function $G(\vec \rho,\vec \rho')$ that satisfies the $2$-D Helmholtz equation

$$\nabla^2G(\vec \rho,\vec \rho')+k^2G(\vec \rho,\vec \rho')=\frac{\delta(\rho-\rho')\delta(\phi-\phi')}{\rho'} $$

inside a circle of radius $1$ and boundary condition

$$\left.\frac{\partial G}{\partial \rho}\right|_{\rho =1}=0 \tag 1$$

can be decomposed into the sum of the free-boundary Green's Function and a homogeneous solution.  We can write, therefore,

$$G(\vec \rho,\vec \rho')=-\frac{i}{4}H_0^{(1)}(k|\vec \rho-\vec \rho'|)+\frac{i}{4}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}A_n(k,\rho')J_n(k\rho)e^{in(\phi-\phi')} \tag 2$$

where the free-boundary Green's Function is given in terms of the Hankel Function of the first kind and zero order, $H_0^{(1)}$, and the homogeneous term is expressed in terms of the standing cylindrical wave expansion in which $A_n$ is an expansion coefficient that we will find by enforcing the boundary condition $(1)$.

We will make use of the cylindrical wave expansion for the free-boundary Green's function $-\frac{i}{4}H_0^{(1)}(k|\vec \rho-\vec \rho'|)$

$$-\frac{i}{4}H_0^{(1)}(k|\vec \rho-\vec \rho'|)=-\frac{i}{4}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_n(k\rho_{<})H_n^{(1)}(k\rho_{>})e^{in(\phi-\phi')} \tag 3$$

where $\rho_{<}=\min(\rho,\rho')$ and $\rho_{>}=\max(\rho,\rho')$.  Substitution of $(3)$ into $(2)$ yields

$$G(\vec \rho,\vec \rho')=\frac{i}{4}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(A_nJ_n(k\rho)-J_n(k\rho_{<})H_n^{(1)}(k\rho_{>})\right)e^{in(\phi-\phi')} \tag 4$$

Now, enforcing the boundary condition $(1)$ on $(4)$, we find the coefficient $A_n$ can be expressed as

$$A_n=\frac{H_n^{(1)'}(k)J_n(k\rho')}{J_n'(k)}$$

Finally, we have the Green's Function

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{G(\vec \rho,\vec \rho')=\frac{i}{4}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{H_n^{(1)'}(k)}{J_n'(k)}J_n(k\rho')J_n(k\rho)-J_n(k\rho_{<})H_n^{(1)}(k\rho_{>})\right)e^{in(\phi-\phi')} }$$

expressed in terms of a cylindrical wave expansion.

We can see immediately that the solution to the exterior problem is then

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{G(\vec \rho,\vec \rho')=\frac{i}{4}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{J_n'(k)}{H_n^{(1)'}(k)}H_n^{(1)}(k\rho')H_n^{(1)}(k\rho)-J_n(k\rho_{<})H_n^{(1)}(k\rho_{>})\right)e^{in(\phi-\phi')} }$$

Comment: Thanks for you effort - I'm just wondering how did you find this homogeneous term that is expressed in terms of the standing cylindrical wave expansion? Also could you please explain in more detail how you go from the interior solution to the exterior?

Comment: @Jack You're welcome.  My pleasure.  The cylindrical harmonic expansion for the homogeneous term can be derived using, say, separation of variables of the two-dimensional Helmholtz equation.  Using that approach, one also can obtain the free-space Green's function expansion of $H_0(k|\vec \rho -\vec \rho'|)$.  To go from the interior to exterior solutions, we replace $J_n$ with $H_n^{(1)}$ in the homogeneous solution since in the exterior, $H_n$ isn't singular and represents a traveling wave solution that decays exponentially for $\text{Im}(k)>0$.